# Celery worker with multithreading - how to update results concurently

Tags: multithreading, queue, celery

I created a Flask API with a Celery worker. User fires "start tests" button which makes a POST request that returns url which user can use to get results of tests every 5 seconds (needed to update fontend progress bar). The Celery task includes threading. My goal is to update Celery task state based on the results of threads concurently. I don't want to wait until all my threads finish to return their result. My Celery task looks like this:

```
@celery.task(bind=True)  # bind argument instructs Celery to send a "self" argument and use it to record status updates
def run_tests(self, dialog_cases):
    """
    Testing running as a background task
    """
    results = []
    test_case_no = 1
    test_controller = TestController(dialog_cases)
    bot_config = [test_controller.url, test_controller.headers, test_controller.db_name]
    threads = []
    queue = Queue()
    start = time.perf_counter()
    threads_list = list()
    for test_case in test_controller.test_cases:
        t = Thread(target=queue.put({randint(0,1000): TestCase(test_case, bot_config)}))
        t.start()
        threads_list.append(t)

    for t in threads_list:
        t.join()
    results_dict_list = [queue.get() for _ in range(len(test_controller.test_cases))]
    for result in results_dict_list:
        for key, value in result.items():
            cprint.info(f"{key}, {value.test_failed}")
```

Now: the TestCase is an object that on creation runs a function that makes a few iterations and afterwards returns whether the test failed or passed. I have another Flask endpoint which returns the status of the tasks. Question is how to get the value returned by threads simultanously without having to wait until they are all finished? I tried Queue but this can only return results when everything is over.

Comment: If you already using Celery, why don't you use it concurrency/queueing capabilities instead of implementing it by yourself? what about `chord`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use [update_state](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/reference/celery.app.task.html#celery.app.task.Task.update_state) to modify state of the task, from each of those threads if that is what you want. Furthermore, you can create your own, [custom states](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/tasks.html#custom-states). As you want to know result of each test the moment it is finished, it seems like a good idea to have a custom state for teach test that you update from each thread durint runtime.

An alterantive is to refactor your code so each test is actually a Celery task. Then you use [Chord](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/canvas.html#chords) or Group primitives to build your workflow. As you want to know the state during runtime, then perhaps Group is better because then you can monitor the state of the GroupResult object...

Comment: Thanks for your help - in the end I decided to abandon Celery though and I switched to a different approach where I save the result of each test (each thread) in Mongodb along with it's 'id' provided in the POST method + I created an endpoint that returns the result of the specific test id. Turned out to be way easier ;)

Comment: Well, if you do not need to distribute your tasks then no need for anything like Celery...